# image convolution with Scipy: shifted identity kernel - how is the computation done?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm new to image processing.  Applying the left shifted kernel below on the matrix will indeed left shift the resulting matrix by one step.

```
matrix=np.array([[0,1,2],
                 [3,4,5],
                 [6,7,8]])

kernel=np.array([[0,0,0],
                 [1,0,0],
                 [0,0,0]])
```

The result:

```
 [[1 2 0]
  [4 5 0]
  [7 8 0]]
```

What seems strange to me is that if I 'manually' apply the actual convolve algorithm to the matrix, it appears that the result instead should be shifted 1 step right...  To see this, take the center element of the matrix '4': applying the left shifted kernel on it should imply that the convolved result for that cell should be 0*0 + 0*1 + 0*2 + 1*3 + + 0*4 + 0*5 + 0*6 + 0*7 + 0*8 == 3, that is, the '3' from the left neighbor cell moves right...

What am I missing here ?

[EDIT]: After Hivert's answer, in order to understand it, I implemented my own 'convolve', according to my previous understanding of the convention for the matrix manipulation:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filter

def neighbors(r,c,supermatrix): 
    m = supermatrix[r:r+3,c:c+3] 
return m

def convolve(n,kernel):
    sum = 0
    for (rr,cc),value in np.ndenumerate(n):
        sum += value * kernel[rr,cc]
return sum

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]])

kernel = np.array([[0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0],
               [0,0,1]])

print 'matrix'
print matrix
print 'kernel'
print kernel
print 'result'
print  filter.convolve(matrix,kernel,mode='constant', cval=0)

shape = matrix.shape

# create a 'supermatrix' surrounding the real matrix
# with the borders with zeroes
# insert the real matrix into the center of supermatrix

newshape =(shape[0] + 2,shape[1] + 2) 
sm = np.zeros(newshape,dtype=np.int)
sm[1:-1,1:-1] = matrix

result = np.zeros(shape,dtype=np.int)


for (r,c),value in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
    n = neighbors(r,c,sm)
    result[r,c] = convolve(n,kernel)

print 'poor mans convolve'
print result
```

This code produces a 'mirrored' result wrt the real convolve function, that is, if I have the identity kernel shifted left, then this code will shift the image to the right, vs. the real convolve function will shift to left and vv.

Thus, the difference is in the convention. Any ideas on why the convention is as it is ?

Comment: How exactly are you calling convolve? It would help if you could add this to the question.

Comment: import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filter

filter.convolve(matrix,kernel,mode='constant', cval=0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have your definition of convolution with the wrong convention. The formula for computing `res[i,j]` is

```
res[i,j] = sum_{k,l} matrix[k,l] kernel[i-(k-1), j-(l-1)]
```

Note the `k-1` and `l-1` are here to consider that the *center* of the kernel as a (0,0) coordinate. Therefore

```
res[1,1] = m[0,0]k[2,2] + m[1,0]k[1,2] + ...
```

which gives the expected result.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to think abt this for a while to understand it.

Comment: I did som further experiments with convolve, thanks to the input from hivert,  and discovered that if if flip the kernel both vertically and horizontally, my 'poor-mans-convolve' produces identical results to that of scipy. I documented those findings at http://goo.gl/SQDe30.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is a question of convention on how you put the kernel.

Comment: Right. Took me a few hours to understand why...! :-) Thanks again for setting me on the right track.

Comment: Since you are new to SO, I allow myself to write that: at this point, if you are Ok with my answer, you probably should accept it.